# Why is VueJs not working showing the data?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

The code below just show the title in curly braces, what is wrong with the VueJs setup?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
  <div id='app'>
    <p>{{ title }}</p>
  </div>
   <script>
     new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            title: 'A Title'
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Placing your code into a JSFiddle doesn't seem to reproduce this issue. That being said, I highly recommend making sure that your script doesn't execute until the page has finished loading. It may help resolve your problem.

Comment: If script is the last tag of the body, the DOM would be ready before script tag executes

Comment: What backend frame work do you use? It might have the same markup as vue.js `{{}}`.

Comment: No backend just plain html the code I submitted is it.

Comment: Are the curly braces temporary and then the page renders your markup?

Comment: What do you mean temporary?

Comment: Are you only seeing {{ title }} or does this disappear after a few moments and then it is replaced with A title?

Comment: seeing {{ title }} permanently.

Comment: Make sure you are not blocking Javascript from rendering, especially with IE.

Comment: Javascript is enabled.

Comment: its ok. what wrong with you ?

Comment: Like **B. Fleming** I copied this into a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1cds2ka/) and was able to render your mark up.  I also, saved a copy to a desktop folder, using Windows 10 OS and did not have any issues.  Additionally, as indicated by **Psidom** if no other backend frame works are involved, e.g. **NodeJS**, then I can't think of any other reason for your issue.

Comment: If there was a delay in processing your page, then I would suggest wrapping your `{{ title }}` element in a `<div>` and use `v-cloak` to prevent markup until page has been rendered. However, you indicated that this is not the case.  So, I am at a loss.

Comment: copied your code and created a static html file. the title totally works on my end

Answer (score 1):

@Web Dev It works fine but you need to do this in script tag

`var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            title: 'A Title'
        }
    });`

And now if you load the page and you will see a title and then you can open the console and change title by typing `app.title = 'My new title'`